# how to calculate forward delta (not spot delta) of a swap?

Tags: swaps, delta

how could I calculate the forward delta of of a cross currency swap?

Suppose I have a swap contract to exchange 1 mio USD with 66.15 mio INR, 3 months later, current Spot is 65.04, how can i calculate the forward delta?

pls be noted it's not about the spot delta.